# How can i Restore sql backup file version 8 on version 12 or 13?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I'm trying to restore a backup file that its version is 8( SQLSERVER2000) on sql server version 13(2016). my problem in restoring a backup file to upper version of sql server. but when i am restoring sql server show me below message :

> Error:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 8.00.0194. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 13.00.1601. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: The error is telling you what to do: ***"Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server."*** The only version of SQL Server that suppotr SQL Server 2000, are 2000, 2005 and 2008(R2).

Comment: There should be a way to restore it. I can't do either of ways that error tells me.

Comment: SQL Serer 2000 has been out of support for almost 6 years; you can't expect Microsoft to make new products back compatible with software they have unsupported for that long. You'll need to get a copy of SQL Server 2008, restore on there, back up and then restore (the new back up) on SQL Server 2014/2016. Depending on your database, you *might* be able to make use of SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a SQL Server 2000 Database to SQL Server 2016](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166205/5203)

Comment: @majidalamdari the way to restore it is what the error clearly says: restore the database to a supported server first, then move it to the newer one. If your company has an MSDN subscription you can download a SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition and restore the backup to it. You may be able to use SQL Server 2008 R2 Express too.

Comment: [This answer by Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99340/480) lists the available options - use Express, buy a 2008R2 Dev edition for $50 (If it's still available), use an Enterprise Trial if available,  or copy the data using bcp/SSIS etc

Comment: Finally, I decide to Download and install SQL 2008 and restore the backup on it. I Found out that I Have no other Choice. Thanks to @Larnu.